# Drawing different shapes through formula in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using an excel sheet to draw few shapes with specific formula. I made this excel sheet by R&D. I want to know little bit more about how formula is working.

Here are few shapes and codes.

```
1 100 |___________|

2 101 |___________

3 102 ____________|

4 103 ------------
```

my sheet is using this formula

`=IF(OR($M20=100,$M20=101,$M20=122,$M20=123),150,"")`

in which `$M20` is cell value. as shown in picture.

```
| code |  shape     |
_____________________
| 103  | ---------- |
```

using above formula if the cell value is given as 103 it draws a straight line (the above is excel sheet. 103 is $M20 column value and other one column is a shape.). same as for other codes in the most above picture. I am having difficulty to understand how formula is drawing those shapes. I am a newbie to this excel work any help would be appreciable. thanks.

[image]

this is the sheet https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7qQFY5M7I5RUEpyTVBMVXhZblJjOVRYb2RMZnVpRnZ4Q3Jz/view?usp=sharing

GN and beams ground floor is the question related sheet tabs.

Comment: if you can post a screenshot of your actual sheet, i think it will help, because I am confused from the data and explanation from your post. they don't seem consistent

Comment: actually i wanted to put that but due to my less reputation it dont let me post a picture

Comment: you can check here https://imgur.com/a/DtbUQyo, one picture is for shapes and other one is being drawn using above formula. can you please see and tell?

Comment: I can also provide the sheet if you want?

Comment: It would definitely help. Those pictures don't show the different cell addresses and that formula doesn't seem to be all there is to what you are explaining.

Comment: Don't add info in comments, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54715219/edit) instead. I've added the image for you

Comment: I have added the sheet thanks

Comment: The formula only shows the number 150 or nothing, as I thought. The 'drawing' is from the [conditional formatting in the worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Chq2.png).